# WPF How to access a control from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-7.1

In new to windows phone development. Can someone help me to learn how can I access a certain control on ViewModel.

Example Scenario:
 I have a listbox and I want to access the listbox from my View Model to add something. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle.  You don't want to access the control itself from the ViewModel.  Rather, bind the ListBox's ItemsSource to a property on the ViewModel.  Then you can add something to the collection directly.

Comment: thanks for this, I just started learning windows phone development that's why I asked this. :)

Comment: Glad to help!  It does take a while to get your head round this way of doing things when you first start out.